# How would I translate “Help me Jesus, for without your grace I am nothing. Merciful Jesus, I place all my trust in you.” into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, ecclesiastical-latin

How would these two sentences translate to Latin?

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice question!

Answer (score 4):

A direct but perhaps too literal translation would be:

> Jesu me adjuves, quia sine gratia tua nihil sum.
> Jesu misericors, tibi solum confido.

Some comments about the choices I made:

- *adjuves* is a jussive subjunctive
- *gratia* is used in *Ave Maria* for *grace*
- *nihil sum* is used by Cicero (IIRC)
- I translated *I place all my trust in you* by *I only trust you*, I don't know if there is a better way to say it.
- I started both sentences with Jesus to reinforce parallelism and impact

Comment: For *I am nothing* part, related questions: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/how-would-you-say-we-are-no-one and https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14023/can-sum-and-nemo-work-together-to-create-a-phrase-meaning-i-am-no-one

;;; Other than that, one can consider using the dative *soli* instead of the adverbial *solum*. I believe there is a subtle difference between them.

Comment: @d_e Thank you for the reference. I could be wrong but I have the impression that using the dative can have a connotation of "to you who are alone" which is not desirable here

Comment: I see what you are saying, but the same can be said about *solum*. to mean "I don't do other things, I only trust you ".

Comment: Shouldn't *misericordis* be in vocative rather than dative here? It's an address, not grammatically linked with the dative that follows.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta If I hadn't added a comma I think it would have been acceptable ("you the merciful") but in this case the vocative works better, thanks!

Comment: @d_e That's a good point, so I don't know if one version is better than the other

Comment: I feel this is better as I expected "misericordia" or "misere" to appear somewhere in the translation.

Answer (score 4):

All these ideas are common in ecclesiastical Latin. So you don't have to reinvent the wheel to have a precise, idiomatic translation.

> Help me Jesus, for without your grace I am nothing. Merciful Jesus, I place all my trust in you.

- *Help me* is **adiuva me** (see, e.gr. Mt 15:25; *adiuva* + pronoun in acc. is the preferred construction to ask for help in the Vulgate (happens several times in the Gospels alone, directed to Jesus).
- *Jesus* as addressing Him is **Iesu** (vocative case)
- *for* (in the sense of *because*) is most frequently **quia** and also **quoniam**
- *without your grace*: as Laravel points, *grace* is *gratia* → *without your grace* **sine tua gratia**.
- *I'm nothing*: **nihil sum** (1 Cor 13:2)

  - There are two relevant close matches to the whole idea of *without your grace I am nothing*:

    1. **sine me nihil potestis facere** (Jo 15:5), *[I am the vine...] whithout me you can do nothing*.
    2. **sine tuo numine nihil est in homine**, *without your help/grace, there's nothing in man* (from the [sequence for Pentecost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veni_Sancte_Spiritus)) //I personally prefer **numine** for *grace* in this context because of this specific verse. Literally it means *nod*, and hence by extension, [*command* and *will*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnumen).
- *Merciful Jesus* would be [**pie Iesu**](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18412/translate-to-latin-merciful-jesus-have-pity-on-me/18413#18413). (See also [this Q/A](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12970/can-the-title-pie-pellicane-iesu-domine-be-shortened))
- *I place all my trust in you*: the shorter *I trust in you* is very common and can be found as **in Te confido** in invocations to the Sacred Heart and the Divine Mercy. Another frequent wording choice is with the verb *spero* (to hope): *sperabo in eum* (I will hope in Him, Ps. 91:2), *in te, Domine, speravi* (a handful of times in the Psalms), etc. Apparently to treat Hope as a noun in this situations is less common. (And hence, to place *all of it* in God,) but I might be proven wrong. You can use the adverb **valde** for *strongly*, or use the more emphatic alternative to *spero* found in the Vulgate, which is [*superspero*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsuperspero) (Ps 199: *in verba tua supersperavi*/I have put my hope in your words.) My choice in this case would be **in Te supersperavi**.

Piecing all together makes:

> **Adiuva me Iesu, quoniam sine tuo numine nihil sum. Pie Iesu, in Te supersperavi.**

Remember that most of the alternatives offered are interchangeable, so you could also say

> **Adiuva me Iesu, quia sine tua gratia nihil sum. Pie Iesu, in Te valde confido**.

Comment: We came up with a close translation but your description is much more detailed than mine, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: FWIW, I found an [example](https://books.google.com/books?id=N9Y8AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA224&lpg=PA224&dq=%22tibi+soli+confido%22&source=bl&ots=uTzvtkDux0&sig=ACfU3U2fAaBLcagl6N9hoXKZ1Fq95N1QYw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi__r3X3ef4AhWrnf0HHeaTAygQ6AF6BAgSEAM#v=onepage&q=%22tibi%20soli%20confido%22&f=false) (no idea what is the context) for *spes* noun which very close to what the OP is after: "*tibi soli confido, spem meam omnem in te colloco*

Comment: Thank you both! // @d_e what an interesting book you've found! I reworded a little to better express that